# Propositional entailment examples

Tags: logic

For Propositional Entailment, What is the best way to evaluate problems such as below as T or F?   Many of them are logically "obvious", but is there a way to deduce in a formulaic manner?   (I'm not trying to get the answers to the problems below,  I have that already, I'm focused on the approach).

Plugging random sets of variables (sentences) for the Γ, Δ etc could work but I have seen that isn't alway obvious in cases where Γ, Δ etc are unsatisfiable.

(a) If Γ ⊨ φ and Δ ⊨ φ, then Γ ∩ Δ ⊨ φ

(b) If Γ ⊨ φ and Δ ⊨ φ, then Γ ∪ Δ ⊨ φ

(c) If Γ ⊨ φ and Δ ⊭ φ, then Γ ∪ Δ ⊨ φ

(d) If Γ ⊭ ψ, then Γ ⊨ ¬ψ

(e) If Γ ⊨ ¬ψ, then Γ ⊭ ψ

Comment: Use the def of $\vDash$.

Comment: Example (e): if $\Gamma \vDash \lnot \psi$, we have that for every *valuation* $v$, if $v(\sigma)=$ **t** for every $\sigma \in \Gamma$, then $v(\lnot \psi)=$ **t**.